# Webpacker deployment to production not creating manifest for some apps in Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, webpacker

I am stuck with deploying Rails apps in production with Webpacker.

Background: I am working on a custom set of Rails templates with the goal of reducing the friction when it comes to spiking new apps. Since the idea is to rapidly build and deploy new apps, I decided to use Webpack (since that is where the puck seems to be going). Using my template, I created 3 apps on my VM. I was able to get one of the three deployed and loading images, styles etc...but I am missing something with the other two. [* I was iterating on the template when I created the first app.]

Server Setup:

- Ubuntu 17.10 x64
- Rails 5.2.rc1
- Ruby 2.5
- Nginx
- Puma
- Webpacker
- Capistrano 3.10.1

APPS: (one working, one not so much working)

1st: (This is the one that is working)

http://www.davechmura.com

https://github.com/dschmura/davechmura_website

2nd: (Not working)

http://www.arborguide.com/

https://github.com/dschmura/arborguide_website

When I look at the production log I am getting this

```
ERROR:


ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application.css in /home/deployer/apps/arborguide_website/releases/20180224143553/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
  1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
     unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
  2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
  3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
  4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
  Your manifest contains:
  {
  }
  ):
```

Also, the arborguide_website/current/public/packs directory is empty. I am guessing that I need to address #4, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how it is working for the davechmura.com app and not the others.

I normally would have raised my hand earlier, but I am relatively new to Webpacker and thought it best to explore the field more. Now however, I am really stuck.

Comment: Are you precompiling/compiling assets?

Comment: Yes. Running RAILS_ENV=production bin/rails assets:precompile works fine and generates assets locally.

Answer (score 4):

Your [Capfile](https://github.com/dschmura/arborguide_website/blob/06659336c4416a113a4e5a81cab8e45ad367c71d/Capfile#L7) has `capistrano/rails` commented out:

```
# require 'capistrano/rails'
```

This means that `cap deploy` will not automatically run `assets:precompile`, which is what triggers the webpack build.